# If one property is passed disallow other Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have this interface:

```
interface ILabelProps {
    labelSize?: LabelSize;
    labelColor?: LabelColor;
    labelWeight?: LabelWeight;
    labelCase?: LabelCase;
    labelVariant?: LabelVariant;
    children: string;
}
```

I'd like to add another property `predefinedLabelType: PredefinedLabelType;` but in case `predefinedLabelType` is passed I'd like to disallow passing any other label property except `children`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one uses 2 interfaces to make and type that satisfies your scenario

```
interface IPreDefinedLabelsProps {
    predefinedLabelType:string,
    labelSize?: never;
    labelColor?: never;
    children?: never;
}

interface INormalLabelsProps {
    predefinedLabelType?:never,
    labelSize?: string;
    labelColor?: string;
    children?: string;
}

type LabelProps = IPreDefinedLabelsProps | INormalLabelsProps

const label:LabelProps = {
    predefinedLabelType: 'test',
    labelSize:'asfd',
    children:'test'
}

const label2:LabelProps = {
    labelSize:'asfd',
    children:'test'
}

const label3:LabelProps = {
    labelSize:'asfd',
    children:'test'
}
```